# flex application(the remote object in flex not able to call java method)

Tags: java

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.modules.ModuleLoader;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.rpc.remoting.mxml.RemoteObject;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.AbstractEvent;
    import mx.rpc.remoting.mxml.RemoteObject;
public function testMethod():void
    {
           var hp:RemoteObject=new RemoteObject();
            var mloader:ModuleLoader=new ModuleLoader();
            Alert.show("2");
            hp.destination="UserCall";
            Alert.show("3");
            hp.testMe(userid1.text,username.text,last.text,con.text,pass.text);
            hp.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,successMethod);
            hp.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,failMethod);
            mloader.url="LoginForm1.swf";
            panel2.setVisible(false); 
            addChild(mloader);
            }
        public function successMethod(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("In success");
        }
        public function failMethod(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("In failed");
        }   
        public function test1():void
        {
            var mloader:ModuleLoader=new ModuleLoader();
            mloader.url="TamarindEx.swf";
            panel2.setVisible(false); 
            addChild(mloader);
        }
]]>
```

I want to call java func from flex.

I have write a function in java, but I am gettnig an error.

Comment: Please add the error message you are seeing. Grammer improved.

Comment: 0 error occured.just they are not able to call java method from flex..

Comment: :8080/WebContent/messagebroker/amf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)..what should i do?